# Search for the element in the database to delete the rows

Tags: php, database

I need some help with my code. I have got the list of elements for `stop_date` data in a database that I would like to delete the rows. I am using the variable called `$current_programme_date` as I'm fetching the list of elements from the database. I would like to search for the element using the variable `$current_programme_date` where I can find the rows in the database that I want to delete.

Here is the elements for the `$current_programme_date`

```
20170727060000
20170727091500
20170727100000
20170727110000
20170727114500
20170727121500
20170727130000
20170727133000
20170727134500
20170727143000
```

Here is the results for `$sql`:

```
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727011000'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727021000'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727030000'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727035000'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727050500'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727013000'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727022000'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727040500'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727050000'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727050500'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727031000'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727040000'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727044500'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727051000'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727053500'
DELETE from programs where stop_date ='20170727020000
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

//open the database File
$db = new SQLite3('myChannel.db');

if(!$db) 
{
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs";

$results = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ) 
{  
   $current_time = (date('Ymdhis'));
   $current_programme_date = ($row['stop_date']); 

  if($current_time > $current_programme_date)
  {
    $sql = "DELETE from programs where stop_date ='$current_programme_date'";
    print_r($sql);
  }
}
?>
```

What I am expecting to do is I want to find each element from the database using the variable `$current_programme_date` to see if I can compare them with my current time that if the programme date format have finished it, example: the element for `$current_programme_date` format is `20170727060000` and my current date format is `20170727180300` so the row should be deleted as the time have already passed.

What happens with my code is they did not find the right elements in the database when I am using the variable as they will fetch all the data and delete all of the rows. I want to find the correct rows in the database when I am comparing the current programme date format with my current date format `20170727180300` as the time have already passed so I can delete the rows I want without delete all of the rows when the current programme date have not been passed from my current date format.

Can you please help me with how I can find the elements in the database to delete the rows when I am using the variable?

**EDIT: When I try this, it did not deleted the rows in the database.**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs";

$results = $db->query($sql);
$stop_date = [];

while($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ) 
{
   $current_time = date('YmdHis');
   $current_programme_date = strtotime($row['stop_date']); // see here :)

   if($current_time > $current_programme_date)
   {
       $stop_date[] = $current_programme_date; //push dates here
   }
}
$sql = 'DELETE FROM programs WHERE stop_date IN ("' . implode('", "', $stop_date) . '")';
print_r($sql);

//finally delete all rows with that stop_date
$db->changes();
echo "deleted succcessfully!";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to find each and every date and delete one by one.Just use
your looping functionality to get `stop_date` into an array then `implode` it with `comma(,)` and finally run a single delete query like this to delete rows.

```
//open the database File
$db = new SQLite3('myChannel.db');

if(!$db) 
{
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs";

$results = $db->query($sql);
$stop_date = [];
while($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ) 
{  
   $current_time = date('YmdHis');
   $current_programme_date = strtotime($row['stop_date']); // see here :)

  if($current_time > $current_programme_date)
  {
    $stop_date[] = $current_programme_date; //push dates here 
    //print_r($sql);
  }
}

// make your delete query here 
$sql = 'DELETE FROM programs 
           WHERE stop_date IN ("' . implode('", "', $stop_date) . '")';

//finally delete all rows with that stop_date
$db->exec($sql);
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example how I can find the single element from the database and then comparing the date with my current time format date `20170727180300` before I could delete the row and find the next element and so on?

Comment: @RobertJones I think you need to fix this line also `(date('YmdHis'));` see the capital `H` its for 24h `h` for 12hr

Comment: oh thank you very much for this, are the code going to look for the correct date format in the database when comparing with my current date format as the time have already been passed so I could delete the correct date formats without delete the whole rows?

Comment: @RobertJones if you convert `stop_date` that you are getting from `database` with `strtotime()` then according to your condition `$current_time > $current_programme_date` it will push only the old `stop_date` s on `$stop_date[]` array before delete

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am getting this `implode(): Invalid arguments passed ` on this line: `$sql = 'DELETE FROM programs 
           WHERE stop_date IN ("' . implode('", "', $current_programme_date) . '")';` any idea??

Comment: @RobertJones my mistake see my edit, use `stop_date` instead of `$current_programme_date`. let me know if it is not working/working ?

Comment: it did not deleted the rows when I have tried it. Please see in my edit question for update code.

Comment: @Robert Jones, what about the $db->exeç($sql); line ?

Comment: Use it as a reference for php and sqlite example it will help u to find what u r missing http://code.runnable.com/Um_7RhUHNhNlAAA3/update-and-delete-rows-for-sqlite3-and-php